# pytest-cov shows incorrect test coverage rate

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

I use pytest and pytest-cov to get the testing coverage report.

My question is:

Why does it show the testing files have 100% coverage(bottom section) whereas they are not fully covered?
Also what do the numbers (18%, 88%, 100% ) mean?

How does pytest know how much the testing code cover?

[image: Testing coverage report]

(with this account I cannot post image directly in my post)

Comment: @buran thanks for your editing to bring the pic into this question.

Comment: The tests are covered because you have instructed `coverage` to cover them. The numbers to the right just show the overall progress (what fraction of overall collected tests were already executed in the current test run).

Comment: hi @hoefling, how did the code instruct the coverage to cover them? Could you please elaborate it? thanks. The code was done by others. In order to calculate the coverage, doesn't the pytest-cov needs to know A(how many functions need to be covered ) and B(how many tests have been writtend) and C(which test coverages which function)?  But I don't see these configuration in the code. This is why I am confused how it figures out the percentage the tests cover.

Comment: You are starting the test run with `—cov=tests`, which means „measure me the code coverage of the `tests` package“. That‘s exactly what you get in the result table.

Comment: hi @hoefling I checked Pytest-cov document. the `--cov` param can point to a module/package or a directory. In my case, I pointed to the directory which contains all test files. So it only knows how many files under tests folder, but how does it know how many files need to be tested(which are in a different folder)?

Comment: I don‘t understand this question. But what I was pointing out: you obviously dont‘t need the coverage of tests, but of the production code - just put a proper name under `—cov`, e.g. `—cov=mypackage`.

Comment: @WinstonFan did you manage to find a solution to this problem?